# Next.js export failing due to import?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I am getting the following error when exporting my nextjs app:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
```

This is my `next.config.js`:

```
import {getBlogPosts} from "./src/api";
import {mapPosts} from "./src/mappers/BlogMapper";
module.exports = {
    async exportPathMap() {
        const response = await getBlogPosts();
        const posts = mapPosts(response);
        const pages = posts.reduce(
            (pages, post) =>
                Object.assign({}, pages, {
                    [`/blog/${post.uid}`]: {page: '/blog/[uid]'},
                }),
            {}
        );
        // combine the map of post pages with the home
        return Object.assign({}, pages, {
            '/': {page: '/'},
        })
    },
};
```

src/api file:

```
import Prismic from "prismic-javascript";
import {Client} from "./prismic-configuration";
export const getBlogPosts = (req) => {
    return Client(req).query(
        Prismic.Predicates.at("document.type", "post"),
        {orderings: "[my.post.date desc]"}
    );
};
export const getBlogPost = (req, uid) => {
    return Client(req).getByUID("post", uid, null);
};
```

I found this in the docs but I am not sure who to resolve it:

> Avoid using new JavaScript features not available in your target
>   Node.js version. next.config.js will not be parsed by Webpack, Babel
>   or TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for `next.config.js:` is written using ES6 syntax.

You should convert it to CommonJS

Try like this:

```
const getBlogPosts = require('./src/api').getBlogPosts
const mapPosts = require('./src/mappers/BlogMapper').mapPosts

module.exports = {
    exportPathMap: async function () {
        const response = await getBlogPosts();
        const posts = mapPosts(response);
        const pages = posts.reduce(
            (pages, post) =>
                Object.assign({}, pages, {
                    [`/blog/${post.uid}`]: {page: '/blog/[uid]'},
                }),
            {}
        );
        // combine the map of post pages with the home
        return Object.assign({}, pages, {
            '/': {page: '/'},
        })
    },
};
```

Comment: I think this is indeed the issue but still get  the '{ Error: Cannot find module './src/api'' error now. Am I exporting in a wrong manner in src/api?

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/Jdruwe/jeroendruwe, just run yarn install and yarn export. If I try to export the function using module.exports i'll get a 'all files must be modules when the '--isolatedmodules' flag is provided' warning, this is preconfigured by next.js but it seems to be required (https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7959)

Comment: Maybe I should do something like this: https://github.com/schoenwaldnils/blog/blob/master/scripts/exportPathMap.js

Comment: Yes, you should convert all the code that is required inside the `next.config.js`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, will convert it now, it's a shame es6 module is not supported, probably for some reason but yea...

Comment: Even if I write a simple module.exports = {... in a test module and try to require it inside the next.config.js it keeps giving me the error mmm